# How to disable Wildfly 9.0.2 trying to serialize certain classes in a clustered application

Tags: java, wildfly, infinispan, wildfly-9

During the set up of a cluster I'm having an issue with WildFly/Infinispan attempting to serialize a number of classes which are fine to be recreated on each instance - although for whatever reason they seem determined to distribute across the cluster.

Initially I thought that the @Stateless annotation would have the effect I wanted, although it throws an issue from not having the correct constructors, so I don't believe this is what we are looking for.

What is the proper way to disable this, or overwrite the method of serialization, on a per-class basis?

Comment: What do you mean by "which are fine to remain completely stateful"? Also, putting the `@Stateful` turns the class into a stateful EJB, which is then automatically distributed across the cluster to provide fault-tolerance.

Comment: You're right, I have been using the wrong annotation, I'll try it again now> 

I've worded it incorrectly, what I meant was that I don't want it clustered - I want each instance having it's own version.

Comment: You should be able to use `@Stateless` or `@Singleton` for this, but in that case you'd need to add a no-args constructor to your class.

Comment: Ok, thank you that makes sense. I'll start doing some re-writing to get rid of the constructors. I'll report back with progress

Comment: Didn't have a measurable effect - it's still trying to serialize what is market with the @Stateless annotation.

Comment: Why would you keep state in a @Stateless bean I wonder?

Comment: Could you add some details? which classes are being serialized? some EJB? or do you put objects in a clustered cache? maybe with their code?

Comment: If you have been writing constructors then that implies that *you* are managing the object lifecycle for them and not the container. If you mark a class as @Stateless then it will be created by the container when you inject it into some other object.

Comment: You mean Wildfly is serializing *instances* of the relevant classes, right?  Not the class objects themselves?

Comment: Are you passing bean instances as arguments to other beans' methods?  If your beans really are stateless, then that should not be necessary.

Comment: I dont believe so, they are all either autowired or retrieved by name from the beanmanager

Answer (score 1):

### The non-answer

Be careful with the approach of disabling serialisation for selected classes. 
Your application might not need to be 'clustered' and not needing replicated sesssions or stateful entities, when run locally or in some limited development environment. However once deployed to test or production it could be clustered. Then it's going to be broken, if you have prevented serialization.

Therefore the best cause of action is to ensure 'serializability' of your classes, rather than force-preventing it.

### Serialization OFF answer

If you insist on disabling serialization, removing `<distributable/>` from your `web.xml` should do the trick.

### Serializing non-serializables answer

By trying to make some classes serializable sometimes you will find that types of certain class members are simply non-serializable and you cannot swap the type for something similar, which would serialize. 
Then use the following trick, providing it is applicable:

```
public class ClassForcedToBeSerializable implements Serializable {

    transient private FileWriter writer; //FileWriter is not serializable!!!
    private final File file;

    public ClassForcedToBeSerializable(File file) throws IOException {
        this.file = file;
        this.writer = new FileWriter(file);
    }

    //FLESH AND BONES HERE

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        in.defaultReadObject();
        if (writer == null) {
            this.writer = new FileWriter(file);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the class includes field of `FileWriter` type. We ensured the object -> bytes serialization by marking it `transient`. However on the remote JVM when this class is being brought back from bytes, your `FileWriter` field field will be `null`. We avoid this problem by recreating it during deserialization (see `readObject()` method).

This example works only because the `File` field carries enough state for `FileWriter` to be successfully recreated.